# Would this be suitable for Bitcoin mining?

Tags: asic

Would *[10 Port Mini USB HUB High Speed 2.0 with Power Adapter Black #198 UK](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/10-Port-Mini-USB-HUB-High-Speed-2-0-with-Power-Adapter-Black-198-UK-/360566754350?pt=UK_Computing_USB_Cables&hash=item53f3740c2e)* (on [eBay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBay)) be suitable for Bitcoin mining?

I have a new PC, so I don't want to damage the motherboard by using the USB ports constantly.

If this isn't suitable, why and what should I be looking for?

Comment: You can't damage your USB ports by using them.

Comment: I am using an ASIC miner that gets very hot. Plenty of forums say to use a powered USB hub?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Been running 3 ASIC miners on a USB hub (similar to the reference above) 24/7 and for a few months now.  No appreciable change on equipment.  Also, buy a USB fan to cool the equipment.  This is the fan I'm using and its working fine.  [USB fan](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Arctic-Cooling-Arctic-Breeze-Portable-Mobile-USB-Fan-/390681051134?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5af667bffe)
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a fan running and the device has stayed completely cool so far, fingers crossed!!

Comment: How have you been doing so far? Are you mining solo or part of a pool?

Comment: Doing well.  Averaging US$12 to US$20 per month.  Though as the difficulty continues to increase, I will need to buy additional ASIC miners to maintain.  I'm mining through Bitminter (http://www.bitminter.com), been good so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between using a USB port, powered or not, and your miner getting hot. Your miner gets hot because it is doing work, see below.

USB powered hubs have the capability to supply a limited amount of power if the device needs it. Devices that have their own power source rarely use power from the hub.

Work requires energy. The way energy works is that all the electricity used by the miner is turned into heat, one way or another. All work also generates heat. Even you.

BTW, what miner are you using?

Comment: I am using the Asic miner Block Erupter.

Comment: If you mean the USB stick it seems that it is powered by the USB hub, there is nothing wrong with that. A USB device tells the hub how much power it requires and the hub decided if that is acceptable.